# Always open a html page in fancyBox iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox

I use Fancybox to display external html pages in fancybox, for example : In `page1` I set a link, which opens `page2` in fancybox `iframe` mode, and that works fine.

The question is :

Is it possible that if somebody tries to enter the URL of `page2`, make `page2` to always open in fancybox from within `page1` instead of the browser window like a normal page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

So page one (`parent.html`), will open page two (`iframed.html`) in fancybox from a link like

```
<a id="openIframe" class="fancybox" href="iframed.html">Open page inside fancybox iframe</a>
```

**Notice** that I set an `ID` and a *class* to the link that will open the iframed page.

Then the script for each page:

### parent.html

parent page should have two specific codes :

- a code to initialize fancybox
- a code to detect when a `hash` is present in the *URL* so it can fire fancybox

so :

```
// initialize fancybox
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    // API options
    type: "iframe" //<== at least this one
});

if (window.location.hash) {
    // detect if URL has hash and trigger fancybox
    $(window.location.hash + ".fancybox").trigger("click");
    // remove hash after fancybox was opened 
    // two methods to cover most browsers
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/i)) {
        var loc = window.location.href;
        index = loc.indexOf('#');
        if (index > 0) {
            window.location = loc.substring(0, index);
        }
    } else {
        history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
    };
};
```

---

Then the second page (`iframed.html`) should have a code that detects if ***itself*** has been opened inside an `iframe` or not (the fancybox iframe in our case).

If not, it should redirect to the parent page, targeting the ID of the link that opens fancybox so :

### iframed.html

```
if (self == top) {
    window.location.href = "parent.html#openIframe";
};
```

**Notice** that `self == top` will return `true` if the page wasn't opened inside an iframe so it redirects to parent.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BLpwX/4/)** (and try also opening the link in a new window/tab)